# Why viewModel returns null value while observeForever used in Unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have written a test method like this:

```
@Test
    fun testGetDoctorsFromServer() {
        val doctorViewModel = DoctorViewModel(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
        val observer = Observer<List<Doctor>> {}
        try {

            doctorViewModel.ldTestData.observeForever(observer)
            doctorViewModel.getDoctorsFromServer()
            val doctors = doctorViewModel.ldTestData.value
            assertEquals(5, doctors?.size)

        } finally {
            doctorViewModel.ldTestData.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
```

but when I run the test I always get assertionfailed error

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :5
Actual   :null
```

I am pretty beginner in unit testing, can anyone recorrect me from what I am missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android LiveData in androidTest returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602979/android-livedata-in-androidtest-returns-null)

Comment: I am doing it in kotlin

Comment: That's not big deal . try out the solution in above link . `Kotlin is indeed java in Disguise`  . Also you can easily convert java classes to Kotlin .

Comment: I have tried that the solution said, but I have some confusion there

Comment: Hello I have tried adding instantTaskExecutorRule like what that answer said but still no result

Answer (score 0):

Because asynchronous operations take time.

Use the following helper:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2017 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class LiveDataTestUtil {

    /**
     * Get the value from a LiveData object. We're waiting for LiveData to emit, for 2 seconds.
     * Once we got a notification via onChanged, we stop observing.
     */
    public static <T> T getValue(final LiveData<T> liveData) throws InterruptedException {
        final Object[] data = new Object[1];
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Observer<T> observer = new Observer<T>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable T o) {
                data[0] = o;
                latch.countDown();
                liveData.removeObserver(this);
            }
        };
        liveData.observeForever(observer);
        latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //noinspection unchecked
        return (T) data[0];
    }
}
```